# Laravel writing the correct variable to the URL and getting the route to pick it up

Tags: laravel

So I have these 2 routes:

```
   /*
 *  Account Activate (GET)
 */
Route::get('/account/activate/{code}', array(
   'as' => 'account-activate',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getActivate'
));

/*
 *  Account Activate EMPTY-CODE (GET)
 */
Route::get('/account/activate/', array(
    'as' => 'account-activate',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getActivateEmpty'
));
```

They are meant to pick up the code from a URL like this: `http://localhost:81/account/activate?duYCzo5TEhmRFMBnDEJUSY4EO81EBCJlOyccVBNxpNPksBg6bJJrvUVV4XnX`

Unfortunately as you can see the URL isn't `activate/code` it's `activate?code`.

This is the code creating the URL (its in a Mail function):

`'link' => URL::route('account-recover-code', $code)`

What can I change to make sure my route works as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
URL::route('account-activate', array('code' => $code));
```

Also use only one route declaration and make the `{code}` optional using `?` like this:

```
Route::get('/account/activate/{code?}', array(
   'as' => 'account-activate',
   'uses' => 'AccountController@getActivate'
));
```

The `URL::route()` method expects the route name, which is `as` value in the route declaration and in `{code?}` the `?` made the parameter optional so if you pass a code to your route then you can pass it as `array('code' => $code)` and if you dont want to pass the parameter then just use following code to generate the `URL`:

```
URL::route('account-activate');
```

In this case your method should be like:

```
public function getActivate($code = NULL)
{
    if(!is_null($code)) {
        // $code is available
    }
    else {
        // $code is not passed
    }
}
```